# move_uploaded_file moving to same folder, no errors

Tags: php, ajax, json, angularjs, rest

I have the following json query posting to my PHP file, where the "uploaded file" is a converted base64 to "xxx" file type:

```
$http.post(
    preUrl + 'assets/new.php',
    data
);
```

I get no errors in the response, and everything seems to transition nicely. The following is my code in PHP:

```
$fileExt = explode("image/", $_POST["poster"])[1];
$fileExt = explode(";", $fileExt)[0];
$filename = uniqid(md5($_POST["poster"])).".".$fileExt;
$poster = convert2image($_POST["poster"], $filename);
/*Everything up to here works as expected, convert2image converts from b64 to file format*/
move_uploaded_file($poster, "/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.org/i.xxxxxx.org/uploads/".$poster);
/*This last line doesn't seem to work, the file is saved into the same directory where the PHP file is*/
```

This is my convert2image script, maybe this has something to do with it?

```
function convert2image($b64, $output_file){
    $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");

    $data = explode(',', $b64);

    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1]));
    fclose($ifp);

    return $output_file;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move_uploaded_file used only for files which are uploaded within file input field into tmp folder which is specified in your php.ini config

in your case you should to use **copy** or **rename**

**UPD.**
also it is useless to save file with one name and after rename it.